# IIf condition to check Tablix is present or not

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to display an image if Name contains a "," in it e.g. (Annie, Peter) - then display image. Based on that my image will be visible or not. I used a condition like

`=IIf(Fields!Names.Value Like "*,*", false, true))`

Which says if the name contains "*,*" then show my image else hide image. this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: try `IndexOf(",") > -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
SELECT IIf(' Annie, Peter' Like '%,%', 0, 1)
```

Your example below

```
=IIf(Fields!Names.Value Like '%,%', 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code :

=IIF(Fields!Names.Value.Contains(","),false, true)